# 'phonegap run android' gives 'ENOENT, no such file or directory' error

Tags: android, macos, cordova

I'm trying run my phonegap project called 'weather' in mac Os, I check my ANDROID_HOME PATH in the .bash_profile.

This is the .bash_profile:

```
export TERM="xterm-color"
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/platform-tools
alias ls="ls -G"
alias composer="php /usr/bin/composer.phar"
export PS1="\e[1;30m\][\e[\e[1;30m\]\e[1;33m\] \u@\H \[\e[1;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] \e[1;30m\]]\n[\[ \e[1;31m\]\T\[\e[0m\]\e[1;30m\] ] > \e[37m\]"
```

But when I run 'phonegap run android' command I get the following error:
[image: screenshot]

Do I need to check something else?

Comment: try create a fake one, icon.png